# Child element onclick in parent element onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I have a "checkbook" in a "div tag", "div tag" that has been 
registered an onclick event, when I clicked on the checkbox, it will call the event of "div tag", how to just catch the event of "checkbook ", I tried "z-index" for checkbok but did not work

Comment: can you please add your code so we can help you out.

Comment: You need to read an article on propagation. That's the issue you have here. You are treating a JavaScript issue with HTML by using z-index. Just go here and it'll all make much more sense: https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/

Comment: I have added code to my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `e.stopPropagation();` to stop [event bubbling](https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/).

```js
$('.comment_item').on('click', (e) => {
  console.log('.comment_item');
});

$('.check-item').on('click', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation(); // stops event bubbling
  console.log('.check-item');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="comment_item">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check-item">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this will resolve your issue i added `if (e.target !== this)`.

```js
$('.comment_item').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;
  
  alert( 'comment_item' );
});

$('.check-item').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;
  
  alert( 'check-item' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment_item">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-item">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried using the method stopPropagation of Nidhin Joseph and it worked, thank you for answer <3

Answer (score 0):

I have added code to my question

```
<div class="comment_item">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-item">
</div>

<script>

    $('.comment_item').on('click', ... );

    $('.check-item').on('click', ... ); // it'll call event of comment_item class

</script>
```

Comment: this is not the question

Answer (score 0):

Use the native checkbox `.onchange` event.

```
document.querySelector("checkbox").addEventListener("change", function({
  console.log(this.checked)
}, false);
```